# include NAs as factor in seaborn boxplot

Tags: python, seaborn

Can I show missing data as extra factor in seaborn? Googling for a while now.

This is the simple code I am using:

```
ax = sns.boxplot(data=df, x=x, y=y)
```

There is an option such as dropna for value_counts:

```
df['bla'].value_counts(dropna = False)
```

but I could not find it for boxplots. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't.
At least, not directly with seaborn.

Issues related to NaN values have been opened in seaborn [for lineplot](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1552), or [pairplot](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/856). However a [ticket from 2014](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/170) seems to indicate that seaborn ignores missing values starting from 0.4. It can be confirmed from seaborn's source code [categorical.py](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/master/seaborn/categorical.py)

```
box_data = remove_na(group_data)
```

The best I could come up with is to create an extra categorical column that expresses the valid/invalid column data status.

Then I would do 2 subplots :
 - a counplot that shows the nb of valid/invalid data for the column you are focusing on
 - some convential seaborn plot based on that column

Additionnaly, it is possible to access the boxplots in order to [show the nb of points taken into account for each boxplot](https://python-graph-gallery.com/38-show-number-of-observation-on-boxplot/).
*Similar could be done for barplots.*

Another approach is to use the value_count intel and add it to plot as an [annotation](https://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html)

Example:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

def custom(val):
    if val >= 0.0:
        return np.NaN
    return val

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(500, 3))
df = df.rename(index=int, columns={0: 'col_1', 1: 'col_2', 2: 'col_3'})
df['four'] = 'bar'
df['five'] = df['col_1'] > 0
df['category'] = pd.cut(df['col_2'], bins=3, labels=['titi', 'tata', 'toto'])
df['col_3'] = df['col_1'].apply(custom)
df['is_col_3_na'] = pd.isna(df['col_3'])

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
validdf = df[(df['is_col_3_na'] == False)].copy()

sns.countplot(data=df, x='is_col_3_na', ax=ax1).set_title('col_3 valid/invalid data ratios')
sns.boxplot(data=validdf, x='category', y='col_3',
            #hue="category",
            ax=ax2)

print(df['is_col_3_na'].describe())
print(df['is_col_3_na'].value_counts())

# start: taken from https://python-graph-gallery.com/38-show-number-of-observation-on-boxplot/
# with proper modifications
# Calculate number of obs per group & median to position labels
medians = validdf.groupby(['category'])['col_3'].median().values
nobs = validdf['category'].value_counts().values
nobs = [str(x) for x in nobs.tolist()]
nobs = ["n: " + i for i in nobs]

# Add it to the plot
pos = range(len(nobs))
for tick, label in zip(pos, ax2.get_xticklabels()):
    ax2.text(pos[tick], medians[tick] + 0.03, nobs[tick],
             horizontalalignment='center', size='x-small', color='b', weight='semibold')
# end: taken from https://python-graph-gallery.com/38-show-number-of-observation-on-boxplot/
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Console prints (concerning the column 'col_3'):

```
count      500
unique       2
top       True
freq       254
Name: is_col_3_na, dtype: object

True     254
False    246
Name: is_col_3_na, dtype: int64
```